# awk create a bulk MySQL insert from csv

Tags: mysql, linux, sed, awk

I have a huge CSV file with data, I'm trying to generate mySQL bulk insert statement.

Data presented as follows in CSV

```
90927597|1356976813998|1356976814177|1356976817457|17756249959|17756249959|18663111085|17753220005|1090917|1775624995900|A
90927599|1356976813098|1356976814797|1356976823738|12562175250|12562175250|12566502514|12565207040|1890362|1256217525000|A
90927602|1356976813098|1356976814797|1356976823738|12562175250|12562175250|12566502514|12565207040|1890362|1256217525000|A
90927603|1356976813098|1356976814797|1356976823738|12562175250|12562175250|12566502514|12565207040|1890362|1256217525000|A
```

I'm looking to create a bulk insert that will combine every 2 rows into single insert statement

MySQL statement with desired output

```
insert into data (90927597,1356976813998,1356976814177,1356976817457,17756249959,17756249959,18663111085,17753220005,1090917,1775624995900,A,90927599,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
insert into data (90927602,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A, 90927603,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
{
    $1 = $1
    head = ( (NR%2) == 1 ? tail "insert into data (" : "," )
    printf "%s%s", head, $0
    tail = ");\n"
}
END { printf "%s", tail }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
insert into data (90927597,1356976813998,1356976814177,1356976817457,17756249959,17756249959,18663111085,17753220005,1090917,1775624995900,A,90927599,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
insert into data (90927602,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A,90927603,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, can I limit number of records per insert? say 100 records for each insert? is it possible?

Comment: What's a record? Where do the "A"s belong? Post some REPRESENTATIVE input and expected output as it's very frustrating when we answer one question and then you say "oh, no, actually I want to do something different" and then we have to figure out what that is by reading iterations of comments.

Comment: With all due respect Ed, the limit question is mentioned in the body of my question, and I didn't want to ask for extras after getting answered.
Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: You're right you do mention 100 there, but people put LOTS of unimportant stuff in their questions and that seemed to be totally unimportant when I (and apparently others) read your question since your sample input and expected output shows all of your input lines going into 1 output line - THAT sample input/output is what is important. If you want to take SOME input lines at a time and group them in multiple output lines then show that, e.g. using say 10 lines of input and grouping them, say, 3 at a time instead of 100 at a time in the output.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, for that I apologize, its true what you said, thanks for your assistance and your time.

Comment: No problem, and if you do decide to update your question with the representative sample input and expected output, I'd be happy to have another crack at it.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your new sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s","insert into date ("}$NF{gsub(/\|/,",");printf "%s",$0}END{print ");"}' file
insert into date (90927597,1356976813998,1356976814177,1356976817457,17756249959,17756249959,18663111085,17753220005,1090917,1775624995900,A90927599,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
```

A more concise way using `tr`:

```
$ echo "insert into date ($(tr -d '\n' < file));" | tr '|' ','
insert into date (90927597,1356976813998,1356976814177,1356976817457,17756249959,17756249959,18663111085,17753220005,1090917,1775624995900,A90927599,1356976813098,1356976814797,1356976823738,12562175250,12562175250,12566502514,12565207040,1890362,1256217525000,A);
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a  way to limit awk print option to 100 lines per statement?

Comment: `print` prints one line per statement and I don't use `print`.. please clarify what you mean.

Comment: right now, using your solution, I can create one big file with huge single bulk insert statement which has thousands of records.
can I split that? into multiple bulk statements? each lets say has 100 records?